# How to convert list of list to dictionary

Tags: python

`event = [['col1','col2','col3'], ['A','B','C'],  ['G','H','I'],  ['J','K','L']]`

- I have list of list
- first list is keys
- rest are values

Expected out
 `[{'col1': 'A', 'col2':'B'},{'col1': 'G', 'col2':'H'},{'col1': 'J', 'col2':'K'}]`

Code is below

```
list_ = []
for entry in event [1:]:
    row = {key: entry[idx] for idx, key in enumerate(event[0])}
    list_.append(row)
list_
```

My output is

```
[{'col1': 'A', 'col2': 'B', 'col3': 'C'},
 {'col1': 'G', 'col2': 'H', 'col3': 'I'},
 {'col1': 'J', 'col2': 'K', 'col3': 'L'}]
```

- I don't want to append `col3` only need to add first 2 column

Comment: So you want to make a list of dictionaries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can slice `event[0]` with `[:-1]` to ignore the last value

```
event = [['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['G', 'H', 'I'], ['J', 'K', 'L']]
list_ = []
for entry in event[1:]:
    row = {key: entry[idx] for idx, key in enumerate(event[0][:-1])}
    list_.append(row)

print(list_) # [{'col1': 'A', 'col2': 'B'}, {'col1': 'G', 'col2': 'H'}, {'col1': 'J', 'col2': 'K'}]
```

If you want to edit the names you can add a condition to check the values. With list comprehensions

```
list_ = [{'country' if key == 'col1' else 'type': entry[idx] for idx, key in enumerate(event[0][:-1])} for entry in event[1:]]
```

Comment: just adding one more thing, if i want to rename `col1` to `country`, and `col2` to `type` what should i do

Comment: @sim change `key` to `'country' if key == 'col1' else 'type'`

Comment: is there any way like i would  pass in if loops like below  so that the renaming will be in control of mine with out else loop . `list_ = [{'country' if key == 'col1'  'country' if key == 'col2': entry[idx] for idx, key in enumerate(event[0][:-1])} for entry in event[1:]]
`

Comment: @sim I think the simplest solution will be to iterate over `event[0]` and edit it before the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip` in a list comprehension:

```
>>> list(dict(zip(event[0][:-1],values[:-1])) for values in event[1:])
[{'col1': 'A', 'col2': 'B'},
 {'col1': 'G', 'col2': 'H'},
 {'col1': 'J', 'col2': 'K'}]
```

Comment: just adding one more thing, if i want to rename col1 to country, and col2 to type what should i do –

Comment: `list(dict(zip(['country', 'type'],values[:-1])) for values in event[1:])`